# how to select two specific words in a string and from the second word to the end of the string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have a request that gives me back this string:

secret: SAXH7PWSK23365M2QU public: GDJREP4P3JN3YUOXBOPJK6YFHE

From all of this string I need only the characters after secret: and before public:

secret: and public: and the characters after public: should be deleted or just not used.
I use react js.

What regex expression can I use for this case?

If there are any solution without regex, they are also welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `match` with a capture group:

```js
var input = "secret: SAXH7PWSK23365M2QU public: GDJREP4P3JN3YUOXBOPJK6YFHE";
var secret = input.match(/\bsecret:\s*(\S+)/)[1];
console.log(secret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just match the uppercase and numbers:

```js
let string = 'secret: SAXH7PWSK23365M2QU public: GDJREP4P3JN3YUOXBOPJK6YFHE';
let res = string.match(/[A-Z0-9]+/)[0];
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

My take on getting what you need without regex...

```
let string = 'secret:...';
let stringParts = string.split(':');

let secretCode = stringParts[1].trim();

let finalCode = secretCode.replace(' public:', '');
```